# NoClassDefFoundError for new dependency in project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I'm working with a project in Eclipse that has 2 projects; a product and a plugin called views.

I added SVNKit v1.3.5 as a dependency in the views' pom.xml file as such:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

After executing Maven 2 Tools > Generate Eclipse Artifacts (from cache) on the views plugin, the build is successful as it downloads SVNKit from repo1.maven.org/maven2/...etc.

I proceed and execute Maven 2 Tools > Generate OSGi Bundle Manifest and Copy Resources on the views plugin, and the build is successful.

I then run Maven 2 Tools > Generate and Set Target Platform on the product, and set the Run Configurations as I always do for other projects.

The product is set as an eclipse application, and the plugins are validated with no errors.

I can write code and it detects the classes and has no problem during compile-time; the problem is when the program needs the classes during run-time.

I run the product and it works fine, until I get to the UI pop-up window which requires any class file from SVNKit. The window simply doesn't pop-up, and the console shows:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-07-19 10:07:10.242
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException
```

I've tried solving this issue, but have encountered the same error over and over no matter what "fix" I've tried. The classpath is correct, as it points to the m2 repo as it does to the other dependencies:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.3.5/svnkit-1.3.5.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.3.5/svnkit-1.3.5-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute value="jar:file:/<details omitted>/.m2/repository/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.3.5/svnkit-1.3.5-javadoc.jar!/" name="javadoc_location"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/trilead-ssh2/build213-svnkit-1.3-patch/trilead-ssh2-build213-svnkit-1.3-patch.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/tmatesoft/sqljet/sqljet/1.0.4/sqljet-1.0.4.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/tmatesoft/sqljet/sqljet/1.0.4/sqljet-1.0.4-sources.jar"/>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
SVNKit v1.3.5's manifest file is quite short compared to the other than I have in my referenced libraries:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_15-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

The other libraries have more information, such as export-package, bundle version, bundle name, import-packages, etc... Could that be the issue? If so, I've tried Google-ing for a manifest bundle file for SVNKit 1.3.5, but have not been able to find anything.

Comment: What repositories are you using? Did you try a maven clean?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a clean as well as deleting the m2 repo manually. repo1.maven.org/maven2 is the only external repo that is being used, the others are internal and don't have SVNKit in them.

I have also tried downloading various versions of SVNKit as jar files, and added them to maven using the command mvn install:install ...etc, but that didn't make any difference either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the scope to `<scope>provided</scope>` instead of `compile`.

The default scope is *compile*, meaning that the dependency is not present at runtime. For this, you use the *provided* scope. More about scopes in maven dependencies on Apache's [Introduction to Maven Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still facing the same problem after trying to set it as provided and running the Maven generates on the projects.

Comment: I've added more information to the bottom of the main post, if that helps.

Comment: This is not correct. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths. I.e. such dependency is available in compile, runtime and test classpaths.